# Splitting a string by multiple delimiters (comma, semicolon, /)?

Tags: python

I have a python string:

```
names = "John, Paul; Sally/Frank"
```

I want to split the string by , ; /. I have tried:

```
names.split(",")
```

but am unsure of how to split the string by ALL the delimiters which are the comma semicolon and slash. I also do not want any white space between the characters to appear. For example, with names after splitting the string, I would want it to be a list that looks like:

```
["John", "Paul", "Sally", "Frank"]
```

with no spaces on any of the individual names.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
re.split('[,;/ ]+', names)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in pure python:

```
names = "John, Paul; Sally/Frank"
delims = [",", ";", "/"]

for x in delims[1:]:
  names = names.replace(x, delims[0])
names.split(",")
```

But @blhsing's answer is good and `re` is in the stdlib so I don't see why you wouldn't use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gencomp to replace delimeters and then split:

```
names = "John, Paul; Sally/Frank"

''.join(',' if i in ';/' else i for i in names).split(',')
# ['John', ' Paul', ' Sally', 'Frank']
```